# Understanding function in scala

Tags: scala, function

The question is strictly about Scala syntax, although it contains some code from akka (as an example).

I'm pretty new to Scala. Digging into source code of akka I came up with the following pretty strange method:

```
def transform[C]
 (f: ExecutionContext ⇒ Materializer ⇒ Future[B] ⇒ Future[C]): Unmarshaller[A, C] =
Unmarshaller.withMaterializer { implicit ec ⇒ implicit mat ⇒ a ⇒ f(ec)(mat)(this(a)) }
```

where `Unmarshaller.withMaterializer` defined as

```
  def withMaterializer[A, B](f: ExecutionContext ⇒ Materializer => A ⇒ Future[B]): Unmarshaller[A, B]
```

What's going on here? What is the scary function `f: ExecutionContext => Materializer => Future[B] => Future[C]`. And what seemed more strange to me was the sequence of `implicit`s: `implicit ec => implicit mat => a => f(ec)(mat)(this(a))` although `withMaterializer` does not have implicit parameters at all.

What does implicit mean in such sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f: ExecutionContext => Materializer => Future[B] => Future[C]` is nothing more than a curried function, so you call it like `f(ec)(mat)(this(a))` with multiple parameter lists (well, technically parameters lists don't belong to the same function unlike `def f(...)(...)`, but those are details). In other words `f` can be written as:

```
f: ExecutionContext => { Materializer => { Future[B] => Future[C] } }`
```

(function which returns a function, which returns yet another function)

Now if you look at `f(ec)(mat)(this(a))` there is a call `this(a)`, which is defined just above `transform`:

```
def apply(value: A)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, materializer: Materializer): Future[B]
```

(`this(a)` is simply a call to `this.apply(a)`). Now `apply` has two implicit parameters, namely `ec: ExecutionContext` and `materializer:Materializer`, so to call it like `this(a)` you need two implicit values. Which is exactly what definition `implicit ec ⇒ implicit mat ⇒ a ⇒ f(ec)(mat)(this(a))` means. It declares `ec` and `mat` as implicits for all nested function bodies so `this(a)` can pick them up. Another possibility would be to write:

```
ec ⇒ mat ⇒ a ⇒ f(ec)(mat)(this(a)(ec, mat))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda with currying and implicit parameters (which are supposed to be in scope of the declaration).

The "scary" function type syntax is [*currying*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying): a function of one argument which takes `ExecutionContext` and returns another function of one argument that takes `Materializer` and returns another function, ... etc. Another thing is [implicit arguments](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#implicit-parameters).

Here's a simpler example of a similar construction:

```
implicit val implicitInt: Int = 5
implicit val implicitString: String = "0"

val f: Int => String => String = {
  implicit a => {
    implicit b => {
      a.toString + b
    }
  }
}
```

Here `f` is a curried function that takes `Int` and returns a function that takes `String` and returns `String`. The general syntax for a function value declaration is `val f = { argument => ... }`, so if you make this argument implicit, it means that there has to be an instance of this type in the scope which will work as *default* value. You can still apply `f` to some arguments: `f(1)("")`, because it's still a function.

You could rewrite the code you're asking about much more verbosely by defining nested functions for every step:

```
def transform[C](f: ExecutionContext ⇒ Materializer ⇒ Future[B] ⇒ Future[C]): Unmarshaller[A, C] = {

  def getExecutionContext(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Materializer => (A => Future[B]) = {

    def getMaterializer(implicit mat: Materializer): A => Future[B] = {

      def applyF(a: A): Future[B] = f(ec)(mat)(this(a))
      applyF // : A => Future[B]
    }

    getMaterializer // : Materializer => (A => Future[B])
  }

  Unmarshaller.withMaterializer(
    getExecutionContext // : ExecutionContext => (Materializer => (A => Future[B]))
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can call your `f` without parameters to utilize implicit values. It works for methods only. `implicit` in function literal means that argument is implicit inside function body.

Comment: You are right. `f` is not usable as a method with default parameters. I just tried to illustrate that construction with a simpler example, but took it out of the context.